# problem with 'store.get' ...however other API calls seem functional

Tags: node.js, express, store

I am using the 'store' ("https://www.npmjs.com/package/store") module with a Node.js Express script.  It seems mostly functional for me, I can create a store key based upon a randomly generated ID, I am able to record data into the store, and loop through the 'key' and 'values' to ensure they exist.  My issue is with the 'store.get' command not returning individual values...here is my code:

```
...

var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const shortid = require('shortid');

// create application/x-www-form-urlencoded parser
var urlencodedParser = bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false })
var _newToken = shortid.generate();

store.set(_newToken, { name: user.username, birthdate: user.birthdate, joinup: user.legacy, los: user.service, email: user.email })
//works fine, information is recorded in the store using a "key" of "_newToken" (a randomly generated ID) 

res.redirect('/members/dash/' + _newToken);

...

app.get('/members/dash/:tempid', urlencodedParser, function (req, res) {

var _member_info = [];

console.log(req.params);  //works fine, prints the randomly generated ID 'key' in the URL parameter...

// Loop over all stored values
store.each(function(value, key) {
console.log(key, '==', value)  //works fine, prints key and each value to console...
_member_info.push(JSON.stringify(value));  
});

console.log('contents of member array: ' + _member_info);  //works fine, prints seeded array to console... 

console.log('RETREIVE NAME: ' + store.get(req.params).name);  //throws 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined' ...why??

// Remove current entry
store.remove(req.params);  //seems to work fine, no error

});
```

Has anybody used this module before that can explain what my issue is?  It seems to be a very nice solution to pass temporary data around however I cannot understand why I cannot access the individual pieces of the stored information using the '.get' command...when the 'store.set', 'store.each', and 'store.remove' all seem to be working.  I thank you in advance.

I have made the following modification...to instead pass a string to the 'store.get' command, however I still get the same error...

```
var _member_convert = JSON.stringify(req.params);
var _splits = _member_convert.split(":");

console.log('TEST RETRIEVE: ' + store.get(_splits[1]).name);  //throws same error as previous
```

Here is the output of the console log:

```
console.log(req.params);
console.log('req.params JSON: ' + _member_convert + " ...splits " + _splits); 
console.log('TEST RETRIEVE: ' + store.get(_splits[1]).name);  //error below throws here

{ tempid: 'xg_KO6Z9' }
req.params JSON: {"tempid":"xg_KO6Z9"} ...splits {"tempid","xg_KO6Z9"}
xg_KO6Z9 == { name: 'admin',  //printout from the 'store.each' here
birthdate: '3-14-1982',
joinup: '2019-12-16',
los: 'unknown',
email: 'me@somehost.com' }
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined  //'store.get' error thrown
at c:\Users\develop\nodejs\easyrtc_p2p\p2p_server_H.js:1658:54
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\develop\nodejs\easyrtc_p2p\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (c:\Users\develop\nodejs\easyrtc_p2p\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at urlencodedParser (c:\Users\develop\nodejs\easyrtc_p2p\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\urlencoded.js:91:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\develop\nodejs\easyrtc_p2p\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (c:\Users\develop\nodejs\easyrtc_p2p\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:137:13)
at Route.dispatch (c:\Users\develop\nodejs\easyrtc_p2p\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\develop\nodejs\easyrtc_p2p\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at c:\Users\develop\nodejs\easyrtc_p2p\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:281:22
at param (c:\Users\develop\nodejs\easyrtc_p2p\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:354:14)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason is you passing `req.params` which is an `object` and you must pass a `string`

Comment: Thanks for your response.  I converted the 'req.params' to a JSON string and then split at the colon (":"), however passing the string to the 'store.get' produces the same error.  My code above has been edited to reflect these changes.  That also would not explain why the other commands work properly ('store.set', 'store.each', 'store.remove') since I am not passing the string to them, only the original 'req.params' object...

Comment: can you please show what req.params looks like ,
also can you please show us what store keys are?

Comment: My post is edited with the info you requested.  I also tested by replacing the 'randomly generated ID' in the 'store.set'  with a regular string as "Pete", and changed the 'redirect' statement to reflect the parameter as being "Pete" as well ('res.redirect('/members/dash/' + "Pete");')...I saw no change in behavior.

Comment: Are there some examples of the 'store' module in usage I may examine on the net someplace...other than the NPM docs...?  I'd like to see how others are using the module.